# Systemd PrivateTmp=true security implications

Tags: security, systemd, nrpe

I monitor the available disk space on Ubuntu servers using [Nagios Core](https://www.nagios.org/downloads/nagios-core/), [NRPE](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net/nagios-nrpe-server) and [check_disk](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_disk.html).

With previous Ubuntu versions, I used to get an output similar to this:

```
DISK OK - free space: / 43754 MB (80% inode=86%):
```

On Ubuntu 18.04.1, instead, I get:

```
DISK OK - free space: /var/tmp 43754 MB (80% inode=86%):
```

I am shown an incorrect mount point `/var/tmp` for the root `/` partition.
I tracked this behaviour to be dependent on having `PrivateTmp=true` in `nagios-nrpe-server.service`:

- I went to look into `/var/tmp` and found a directory named `systemd-private-c5b5d3d362364af19af640147f2cb844-nagios-nrpe-server.service-4uILRy`
- then examined the service definition and noticed `PrivateTmp=true` (which isn't there e.g. for [NRPE2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/nagios-nrpe-server) on Ubuntu 16.04)
- finally, tried deleting the line and the root mountpoint was then detected as `/`

I feel like I'm facing three options:

1. Live with it.
2. Remove `PrivateTmp=true`.
3. Find a reasonable workaround.

I'm inclined to just live with it, but if I were more aware of the implications of not having a private `/tmp` for the service, I could make an informed choice about option 2.

The optimal solution could be to find a workaround, instructing `check_disk` to return the correct mount point information even in this case. Not being able to access the system `/tmp` should not represent an obstacle.

**Question:** Please illustrate the implications of `PrivateTmp=true`, explaining why it would be recommended and in what cases and with what caveats it can be removed.

**Secondary question:** Is there a sensible workaround to make `check_disk` or an equivalent tool display the correct root mountpoint even when run by a service with `PrivateTmp=true`?

---

**Additional info:**

The complete command is: `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/mapper/vg-root`. When run locally, even with the `nagios` user, the output correctly shows `/`. When run remotely from the Nagios server with: `/usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_nrpe2 -H 192.168.1.2 -c check_root`, the output shows `/var/tmp` instead of the expected `/`.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that `PrivateTmp=` caused the problem?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Good question, I edited the OP adding more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior by providing the block device to `check_disk` instead of the mount point.

For example:

```
root@cosmic:~# grep check_root /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg 
command[check_root]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sda1
root@cosmic:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_root
DISK OK - free space: /var/tmp 6451 MB (68% inode=78%);| /var/tmp=3033MB;8010;9011;0;10013
root@cosmic:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sda1
DISK OK - free space: / 6451 MB (68% inode=78%);| /=3033MB;8010;9011;0;10013
```

But by using the mountpoint, I get the expected behavior:

```
root@cosmic:~# grep check_root /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg 
command[check_root]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /
root@cosmic:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_root
DISK OK - free space: / 6451 MB (68% inode=78%);| /=3033MB;8010;9011;0;10013
root@cosmic:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /
DISK OK - free space: / 6451 MB (68% inode=78%);| /=3033MB;8010;9011;0;10013
```

This behavior does seem to be related somehow to setting `PrivateTmp=` in the systemd unit. When I remove this from `nagios-nrpe-server.service`, then `check_disk` returns the expected result when given the block device as well. I played around a bit with a trivial service that just ran `/bin/df` with `PrivateTmp=true` but I couldn't find any obvious problem there. It returned the correct results too.

I would suggest that the best thing to do, if you really need to be able to check disks by block device rather than mount point, is to report an issue to the Nagios NRPE developers so they can actually dig into the code and find whatever it is.

Comment: Great! I had thought about that, but now I don't see any reason why I couldn't use `-p /`. I believe I can drop a line to the Monitoring Plugins Development Team.